# PermissionError 13

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, subprocess, scrapy

Мне нужно на сервере VPS запускать парсер и отправлять все это дело пользователю в телегу. Я сделал на flask вебхук, сделал парсер на scrapy.

Если я запускаю парсер как обычно scrapy crawl <spider_name> то все работает отлично, но как только я пытаюсь его запустить через flask (через запрос к телеге flask, а точнее бот, но это не важно, запускает скрипт через subprocess), вот эту команду

`subprocess.check_output(['scrapy', 'crawl', spider_name])`,

тогда он мне дает ошибку что не найден каталог scrapy (хотя конфиг скрапи лежит в этом же каталоге и из командной строки от root'a запускался замечательно), тогда я решил сделать умнее

`subprocess.check_output(['/var/www/trade_bot/trade_bot/venv/bin/scrapy', 'crawl', spider_name])`

но начал ловить ошибку PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'), тогда я поставил 777 права на этот файл (теперь они выглядят вот так **-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  236 Jul 16 22:06 scrapy**) но и это не помогло, тогда дал все права юзеру **www-data www-data uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),0(root),27(sudo)** все равно та же ошибка, что у меня нет прав, что делать??

Comment: через sudo запусти, или надай пользователю права на файл, или попробуй юзера добавить в групу www-data

Comment: @MyNameIsKitsune, какого именно юзера мне нужно добавить в группу? просто я так понял что www-data итак должен быть в группе www-data, или мне нужно создать нового? тогда как мне указать apache какого юзера я хочу, чтобы он использовал? права задавал на файл, chmod +x scrapy и поставил 777 пермишн, через судо пытался, он возвращает в ответ 1, пытался через subprocess.Popen но он вообще не пишет ничего и скрипт не запускает

Comment: юзер. который запускает скрипт

Comment: или chmod a+x /var/www/trade_bot/trade_bot/venv/bin/scrapy

Comment: @MyNameIsKitsune, поставил chmod a+x все как ты написал
ls -la выдает то же самое -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  236 Jul 16 22:06 scrapy
и ошибка осталась та же PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/trade_bot/trade_bot/venv/bin/scrapy'

Comment: ну я прописал юзеру www-data root и sudo через sudo usermode -aG root sudo www-data, вот его права теперь www-data www-data uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),0(root),27(sudo), это не помогло, или я не то прописал?

Comment: chmod o+x /var/www/trade_bot/trade_bot/venv/bin

Comment: @MyNameIsKitsune не помогло, попробовал и через флаг -R сделать, и на bin навесить, и на scrapy отдельно, все равно ошибка